# Concurrent writes to DB with conditional unique

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am using spring-boot, mysql and JDBC in my application.

I have a table which is like below

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ref` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `userId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(255),
  `count` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `version` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

In this table, I have a column `count` which depends on the combination of unique `ref`, `userId` and `text` columns eg. if the combination of these columns is not present in DB then the count will be 1 but if the combination already exists in DB, the count value will be 0.

I run into the problem, when the two or more users are trying to post with same `ref`, `userId` and `text` at the same time. Out of these request only one should get count as one and other ones as zero.

How can I handle this case when multiple users are trying to post with same values?

Comment: Kindly post some spring java code

Comment: Your design is not very *relational* one. Either move the `count` attribute in a *view* where it will be calculated as a first inster of the particular combination of your keys (add insert timestamp and handle ties) or define a *unique constraint* on your key *plus* the `count` - the first insert with coutn = 1 will be sucessfull, competing session will fail and wil be forced to increase count by one (you change the logic taht all counts > 1 are considered as zero). The advantage of the view solution is that is handels also *deletes* of the unique keys.